# Regex Python extract digits between two strings in a single expression

Tags: python, regex, string, digits

I want only digits existing between two characters in order to get an integer dollar value, e.g. from string:

`"Advance [Extra Value of $1,730,555] in packages 2,3, and 5."`

we want to obtain `"1730555"`.

We can use `\$(.*)\]` to get `"1,730,555"`, but how do we remove the commas in the same expression, while retaining the possibility of arbitrary many commas, ideally getting the number in a single capturing group?

Comment: one option don't use regex to remove the commas, use `replace(',','')`

Comment: Just chain the `.replace(',','')`. A regex engine cannot perform a replacement while extracting at the same time.

Comment: Maybe you could shed some light on the reason you need this to be done in a single regex match operation - as this most likely is not possible. You can't match non-continuous content into a single group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
import re
text = "Advance [Extra Value of $1,730,555] in packages 2,3, and 5."
match = re.findall(r'\$(.*)]',text)[0].replace(',','')
print match
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use split and join:

```
import re

s = "Advance [Extra Value of $1,730,555] in packages 2,3, and 5."

match = re.findall(r'\$([\d,]+)', s)
number = ''.join(match[0].split(','))
print(number)
```

Comment: You don't use the fact that the number needs to be inside `[]`, right?

Comment: For this example my provided solution works. I am just using the fact that there is a $ in front of the number. If there are other numbers with leading $ that must not be returned but only the ones additionally encased in [] then just extend the regex to: '\[.*\$([\d,]+)\]'